# Allow access to folder in IIS website when using Windows Authentication

Tags: iis-7, web-config

I have an IIS7.5 intranet website which I have secured using Windows Authentication.

I want to allow access to a file in a sub-folder of the website without prompting for Windows credentials.

My web.config is shown below. When I browse to http://myserver:9876/SomeFolder/test.html I am still prompted for Windows credentials :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around for the problem, which I thought wasn't possible due to wcf.  I just changed the authentication scheme to 'Anonymous' on "SomeFolder" and it works.

I haven't answered my question, so it still would be interesting to know if my original approach was possible.